# Why does SQLite's LIKE% not work in a JOIN?

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-like

Using the Chinook test database, the following SQL statement works in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE Name LIKE '%the%'
```

Yet if I use JOINs:

```
SELECT * FROM playlist AS pl 
JOIN playlisttrack AS plt ON pl.PlaylistId=plt.PlaylistId 
JOIN track AS t ON plt.TrackId=t.TrackId WHERE pl.Name LIKE '%the%'
```

SQLite fails on the WHERE statement, although MySQL works fine:

[image]

What makes SQLite fail here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have `playlisttrack` and `track` for your `playlist`?

Replace `JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN` to get all `playlist` even if they don't have `playlisttrack` or `track`

Comment: adding left joins give me the same erroneous results for sqlite, but correct results in MySQL as in the above statement

Comment: can you try without the "as" keyword for the table's alias ?

Comment: that was it, using AS and given each "name" column unique titles fixes the problem with sqlite

Answer (score 1):

The LIKE seems to work, as you get the same result.

The problem seems to be multiple columns with the name "Name" in the three tables. I would avoid "SELECT *" and select the columns you need instead, using aliases to make clear what is what.